# How do I grab an http response from a flash object?

Tags: javascript, flash

I know that certain flash objects send HTTP requests to their intended domain. How do I grab the flash object's server's response and store it in a variable in Javascript? I have no code because I'm completely unsure of what to do.

Comment: you want your web page that contains a flash object to intercept the flash objects network traffic? that's unpossible

Comment: as the answer says, and I already said, that's unpossible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly capture HTTP traffic between a Flash object and its host from JavaScript, for several reasons, one of them being security. You can, however, make calls between the Flash object and the SWF container (in this case, the browser running JavaScript) through [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html). This requires coordination between the two sides but it works well, as long as browser version and configuration together allow it to execute.